# Jquery simple pagination doesn't work

Tags: jquery, pagination, jsonp, bing-api

I'm using the Bing API to do internet search. I would like to paginate the results and recently I found a nice Jquery script which is supposed to do that. The script is very simple to understand:

```
$("input#searchbox").keyup(function() {

    //how much items per page to show
    var show_per_page = 60000; 

    //getting the amount of elements inside content div
    var number_of_items = $('#txtresults ul').children().size();

    //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(webResultTotal/show_per_page);
```

The last line is what is determining the amount of pagination numbers: from the Bing API the 'webResultTotal' is the number of total results. So that is divided by the number 'show_per_page'  I have set the amount to 60000 because otherwise the whole thing gets jammed, which is my first problem.

A. I would like to show_per_page 12 but it seems this math is to difficult or whatever so it gets jammed.

B. It only does something at the second keydown while it should paginate on the first keydown.

So in conclusion: How can I get it to paginate at the first keystroke with 12 'show_per_page' without getting jammed?

Here is a demo: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/obukal/3/edit)

I have put the pagination code right after function webResults.

ps I updated the link, I took out all the text results for better view.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the script you've provided on JsBin there seems to be a whole lot of things going wrong, I get 40 JS-warnings - however, the two things you mention in you question work just fine.

- **A** I can set the page number to 12 and it work as expected without getting jammed, I get 12 results per page.
- **B** The code will run on the first keystroke (there is no code to state that it shouldn't), and it does. I only need to type one letter for the results to show. Notice however that you listen for the key UP-event, so it isn't until you release the key that the event will fire. If you type fast I guess it might feel as the search doesn't trigger until the second key stroke.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question...Its not about the results, those are fine. Please take a look at the question, I have updated the link. I took out the div for results for better understanding. The pagination is not finished. The 12 results you are getting are not from the pagination but the Bing api: var WebCount = "Web.Count=12";

Comment: The pagination doesn't work yet. for now Im only interested in showing the numbers, nothing more.